# What is the difference between a += b and a =+ b , also a++ and ++a?

Tags: java

As I mentioned in the title,

What is the difference between a += b and a =+ b , also  a++  and  ++a ? I'm little confused

Comment: In really old versions of C, `=+` was equivalent of `+=`. Dropped for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`

`a = +b` is equivalent to `a = b`

`a++` and `++a` both increment `a` by 1.
The difference is that `a++` returns the value of `a` before the increment whereas `++a` returns the value after the increment.

That is:

```
a = 10;
b = ++a; //a = 11, b = 11

a = 10;
b = a++; //a = 11, b = 10
```

Comment: +1. Re: "`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`": A small pedantic nit: if the evaluation of `a` involves side-effects, then those happen only once. For example, in `foo().x += y`, the `foo` method is called only once, whereas in `foo().x = foo().x + y`, it's called twice (and it could even return a different instance each time, in which case the `x` that's being assigned to is different from the `x` that's being read from).

Answer (score 18):

`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`

`a = +b` is equivalent to `a = b`

`a++` is *postfix increment* and `++a` is *prefix increment*. They do not differ when used in a standalone statement, however their evaluation result differs: `a++` returns the value of `a` *before* incrementing, while `++a` *after*. I.e.

```
int a = 1;
int b = a++; // result: b == 1, a == 2
int c = ++a; // result: c == 3, a == 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have covered the answers to most of your questions. However, they are missing a bit about your second example.

`a = +b` assigns the value of `+b` to `a`. The "unary plus" is a no-operation for numeric types, but a compile-time error on other types of objects (for example, you can't use it with a string). It is provided mainly so you can write numbers with a leading `+` sign when you want to. This is never necessary, but it can improve readability in some circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

[Java operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
a += b;  // a = a + b
a = +b;  // a = b
a++;     // a = a + 1 (returning a if used inside some expression)
++a;     // a = a + 1 (returning a + 1 if used inside some expression)
```

Answer (score 4):

a+=b ========> a=a+b

a=+b ========> a=b

++a will increment the variable and return the incremented value.

a++ will increment the variable but return the value before it was incremented.

Answer (score 2):

```
a += b <=> a = a + b
a =+ b <=> a = b
a++ // post increment, means the value gets used, and after that, a is incremented by one
++a //pre increment, a is incremented by one before the value is used
```

Answer (score 2):

a++ first reads the value of a and then increments its value. ++a first increments the value and then reads it. You can see easily the difference printing them.

```
int a = 4;
System.out.println(a++); // prints 4, after printing, a == 5
System.out.println(++a); // first increments a, then reads its value (6), and that's what got printed.
```

for `a += b` and `a = +b`, @Péter Török has answered clearly before.

Answer (score 1):

- `a += b;` is equivalent to `a = a + b;`.
- `a =+ b;` is equivalent to `a = +b;`. This means `+b` (positive) is assigned to variable `a`.
- `a++` is **post increment** of variable `a`, meaning the value of the variable is used before incrementing by `1`.
- `++a` is **pre-increment** of variable `a`, meaning the value of the variable is incremented by `1` and used after increment.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the difference [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) There are examples for all the cases you mention!