# Why different behavior for increment operator in java and c

Tags: java, c, post-increment

In c :

```
int a = 33;
a = a++;
printf("\n\t a :%d",a); // it'll print 34
```

In Java :

```
int a = 33;
a = a++;
System.out.printf("\n\t a :%d",a); // it'll print 33
```

Why the post increment works correctly in C and why not in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc - the C part is undefined behavior, you can't rely on it (could print anything). The Java part is as per Java spec, i.e. the result you see is the expected behavior.

Comment: In `C`, the code you posted has undefined behavior. It does not "work correctly" because there is no definition of correct behavior for that code! Although in your environment it prints 34, in others it will print 33.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570589/java-i-operation-explanation - for the Java part

Comment: Because they're different languages. Where does it say they must be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

There's a difference between `a++` and `++a`. In Java (at least), each will increment the variable, but the value represented  by the expression is different.

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i++); // 0

int j = 0;
System.out.println(++j); // 1
```

So you're incrementing `a` by 1, but then *setting it back to the original value*.

From [the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

> The increment/decrement operators can be applied before (prefix) or after (postfix) the operand. The code result++; and ++result; will both end in result being incremented by one. The only difference is that the prefix version (++result) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (result++) evaluates to the original value. If you are just performing a simple increment/decrement, it doesn't really matter which version you choose. But if you use this operator in part of a larger expression, the one that you choose may make a significant difference.

Comment: Is this really necessary? It's been answered many times before on the site, and instead you should have flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: This does not really answer OP's question, which is why there appears to be a difference between C and Java.