# difference between + and += in java?

Tags: java, math, sum

Could explain me why there is a difference when I want to sum some numbers?

```
int a = 4;
int b = 6;
int e = 10;

int wynik1 = a += b += e; //so it is 20. 
System.out.println(wynik1);
int wynik2 = a + b + e; 
System.out.println(wynik2); // so it is 46....
```

Should I just use always `+=` instead of `+`? 
I'm confused because when I was learning, for example, loops, I was using `for (int p = 20; p<40; p=p+ 5)` and it was working fine.

Why is it 46?

Comment: say a=1, b=1, a+=b. then the final value of a would be: a = 1 +1. a+=SOMETHING means add something to my current value of a, and assign it to a.

Comment: Another introduction to += is provided by the similar question ["What is the difference between a += b and a =+ b , also a++ and ++a?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098282/)

Comment: Is your question really just "What does += do?"

Comment: the second line is `42`, but if you switched the order of the lines (so that the `+=` operator is **after** the `+` operator, you would have them both be `20`.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases ([exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)) `a += b` as equivalent of `a = a + b`

So

```
int wynik1 = a += b += e; //so it is 20.
```

is same as

```
int wynik1 = (a = a + (b = b + e)); // so it is 20.
```

which means that

- first `b = b + e` will be executed making `b` 6 + 10 = 16
- then since `b` is `16` `a` will be assigned with result of 4 + 16 = 20
- which finally will be assigned to `wynik1`.

So after that line `(a = a + (b = b + e))` (or in your case `a += b += e;`) our variables will hold these values:

- `a = 20`
- `b = 16`
- `e = 10` (`e` didn't change since there was no `e=..` in our code)

This should explain why

```
int wynik2 = a + b + e; //20 + 16 + 10
```

is `46`.

Comment: When I wrote this: (a = a + (b = b + e)) - it is still 46...

Comment: Point of this answer is to show that `a += b += e` is same as `(a = a + (b = b + e))` which kind of explains why results are same.

Answer (score 2):

`+=` is way different from `+`.

`a+b` means add `a` and `b` and do something with the result.

`a += b` means add `a` and `b` and assign the result back to `a`.

In your example I don't think you want to have that kind of side effect in the first expression as you probably want to use the original values in the next expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` operator is distinct from the `+` operator in that it also assigns the result back to the variable.

```
a = a + 5;
a += 5;
```

Are equivalent.

In your example,

```
int wynik1 = a += b += e;
```

Not only is `wynik1` equal to 20, but a is now *also* equal to 20 and b is now 16.  This is why your second line returns 46:

```
   a +  b +  e
= 20 + 16 + 10
= 46
```

Comment: I should note that I've never used `+=` in-line like this (e.g. `int wynik1 = a += b += e;`).  I didn't even know you *could* but I'm not surprised that it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

As for the line:

```
int wynik1 = a += b += e;
```

b will be added with 10,
a with b, which is now 16, so the result is 20

The difference with a simple `+` is that the value of b is changed as well.

You could rewrite this to:

```
b = b + e; //results in b equals16
a = a + b; //results in a equals 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `+=` is a shortcut. 
Doing: `a += 1;` is equivalent to `a = a + 1;`

So, when you do: `int wynik1 = a += b += e;`
is reality you are doing:

```
int wynik1 = (a = a + (b = b + e));
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` just adds numeric values

`+=` adds the value on the right to the variable on the left part

Examples:

```
int a=3;
int b=4;
int c = a+b; // result c==7
c += 1; // result c==8
```

You can also use any other operator, like `- * /`

```
int d = 4;
d -= 3; // result d=1
int e=13;
int f *=3; // result f=39
```

Comment: thanks for your and all answers!

Answer (score 0):

First, note that

```
a += b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a + b;
```

The order of operations for assignment in Java is right to left. So,

```
a += b += e;
```

is

```
b = b + e; //16
a = a + b; //20
wynik1 = a; //20
```

Hence

```
wynik2 = a + b + e; //46
```